# Как найти определенное количество символов @?

Tags: javascript

let str = 'aaa@bbb@c@@cc'

//Должно вывести 4

Comment: Попробуйте циклом, перебрав по символу

Comment: вариант 1 - регулярка, вариант 2 - цикл посимвольно по строке и подсчёт количества

Comment: Самый короткий вариант, который пришел в голову `'aaa@bbb@c@@cc'.split('@').length-1`

Comment: циклом особо не хочется

Comment: я то сделаю в цикле , просто хочется чего нибудь другого)

Comment: ну сделай вначале в цикле... пока твоих попыток хоть что-то сделать не видно совсем..... да и не ясно что в цикле такого плохого

Comment: let str = 'aaa@bbb@c@@cc'

for(let i = 1;str.includes('@'); i++){
    str = str.replace('@','!')
    console.log(i)
}

Comment: вот видишь, ты даже с циклом ужЕ сделал **не**правильно... да ещё реплейсы зачем-то.... а при этом хочешь что-то крутое.

Comment: реплейсы да , но а что перед этим я не то сделал ?

Comment: ну например объясни смысл выражения `for(let i = 1;str.includes('@'); i++)`  подробно

Comment: i плюсуется если в str имеется @ , а там реплейсом заменяются ,символы хотя можно и по другому

Comment: То есть тебя не смущает, что ты не задал циклу условие, когда нужно остановиться (сколько итераций надо делать)? Тебя не смущает тот факт, что includes - будет всегда возвращать true, если в строке будет хоть 1 хоть 2346234 символов `@`? Так что дружочек, тебе для начала базу надо выучить. как писать цикл for банально... и изучить документацию на includes.

Comment: А то ходить не научился, а уже хочешь в соревнованиях по прыжкам с трамплина участвовать))

Comment: теперь буду помнить

Comment: также ты в своём коде ни разу не сравнил по**символьно** данные из строки с искомым.......ни завёл счётчик для подсчёта.....а также *"если в str имеется @"* -- за слово `если ` в программировании отвечает `if`, которого в твоём коде тоже нет  ..... Поэтому для начала освой что-то простое базовое))

Comment: @АлексейШиманский, ну я его код понимаю как.. мы выполняем цикл пока в строке находится "@", в цикле мы заменяем первый "@" на другой символ, и в итоге цикл то остановится, когда закончатся знаки "@" или я что-то не так понимаю?

Answer (score 2):

```
'aaa@bbb@c@@cc'.match(/@/g).length
'aaa@bbb@c@@cc'.split('').filter(s => s === '@').length

const getNumberSymbolOccurrences = (str, find) => 
  str?.split('').filter(s => s === find).length ?? 0

// циклом

const getNumberSymbolOccurrences = (str, find) => {
  if (!str || !find) {
    return 0
  }

  let result = 0
  for (const s of str) {
    if (s === find) {
      result += 1
    }
  }

  return result
}

/* зависит от требований, но если такая функция используется в 
приложении, то
функция должна кидать исключение, если не передан какой либо из 
аргументов. Это делается для того что бы вызывающий код знал об 
ошибке и смог ее обработать.
  if (!str || !find) throw new Error('message')
/*
```

Comment: `('aaa@bbb@c@@cc'.match(/@/g) || []).length` - чтобы при отсутствии символа в строке не получить ошибку. Да и с регуляркой может возникнуть вопрос о экранировании символов

Comment: Вопрос был - Как найти определенное количество символов @? Второй вариант можно сделать безопасным.

Comment: Не обижайтесь - это у меня профдеформация %)

Comment: Нет, я согласен, у Вас тоже хорошая мысль)) Добавил еще одно решение)